# Failed to initialize Angular compilation - Map maximum size exceeded

Tags: javascript, angular

I'm currently working on an Angular 15 project, and having problems with building and serving as my project grow. In the beginning build times were pretty good, but as my project grew build times started getting worse (>30s), and at some point I've reached the point were my project doesn't build or serve at all, displaying the error message `Failed to initialize Angular compilation - Map maximum size exceeded` (after a build time of ~120s).

So far it seems to be happening when I add additional parameters of different classes into a custom class I have implemented, it seems to be increasing exponentially with the number of attributes added. As a short example, the class looks similar to the following:

```
import { ParameterA } from './parameter-a'
...
import { ParameterH } from './parameter-h'

export class ParameterCollection {
  constructor(
    public parameterA: ParameterA,
    ...
    public parameterH: ParameterH,
  ) { }

  static emptyParameter(): ParameterCollection {
    return new ParameterCollection(
      parameterA.emptyParameter(),
      ...
      parameterH.emptyParameter(),
    )
  }

  toObject() {
    return {
      ...this.parameterA.toObject(),
      ...
      ...this.parameterH.toObject(),
    };
  }
}
```

(`toObject()` is a custom implemented function on the parameters).

Does anybody have an idea what might be causing my issues?

EDIT: I'm putting down the complete error message I get when running `ng server` here:

```
./src/app/some.module.ts - Error: Module build failed (from ./node_modules/@ngtools/webpack/src/ivy/index.js):
Error: Emit attempted before Angular Webpack plugin initialization.

Error: Failed to initialize Angular compilation - Map maximum size exceeded
```

Comment: That alone shouldn't be an issue. We have many, many component classes, each taking multiple dependencies. Our build times have remained fairly stable despite having added many new components.

Comment: Yes, personally I would be surprised if this would be the main issue, but at least this is how I can take an influence on this behaviour. Do you have any ideas/suggestions where I could look, or how I could get more detailed information, in my particular case?